# Probability of Maximum of Subset of Multinomial Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, order-statistics, multinomial-distribution

Suppose that I have a random variable $X \sim \text{Multinomial}(N, M, \mathbf{p})$, where $\mathbf{p} = \frac{1}{M} \mathbf{1}$, $N$ is the number of trials, and $M$ is the number of bins.

I want to find out:

$$ P\left(\text{max}\left\{ x_{2}, x_{3}, \ldots, x_{M} \right\} \leq \gamma \right)  $$

In other words, I want to find out the probability that the maximum of all but one of the $x_{i}$ are less than a threshold.

My immediate thought is that because $x_{i} \sim \text{Binomial}\left( N, p \right)$, that the answer would simply be:

$$ P\left(\text{max}\left\{ x_{2}, x_{3}, \ldots, x_{M} \right\} \leq \gamma \right) = \prod_{i=2}^{M} P(x_{i} \leq \gamma) =  P(x_{i} \leq \gamma)^{M-1} $$

Therefore, if I wanted the maximum of all but $k$ of the $x_{i}$, I would have:

$$ P\left(\text{max}\left\{ x_{k+1}, x_{k+2}, \ldots, x_{M} \right\} \leq \gamma \right) = \prod_{i=k+1}^{M} P(x_{i} \leq \gamma) =  P(x_{i} \leq \gamma)^{M-k} $$

However, this doesn't seem to be the case when I compare against a numerical experiment. The figure shows $P(\text{max}\left\{ x_{2}, x_{3} \right\} \leq \gamma)$ when $X \sim \text{Multinomial}\left(N=1000, M=3, p = [\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}]^{T} \right)$. The red curve represents my thoughts above and the blue curve represents the hard data.

So, what am I missing?

[image: Prob of 2 out of 3 Max]

Comment: To approximate the multinomial by a set of iid variables, the Poisson distribution is usually chosen (with $\lambda = N/M$). Because the joint distribution of such Poisson conditioned on the sum being $N$ equals the mutlinomial.

Comment: @leonbloy Hmm interesting. So to do this, each of the $x_{i} \sim \text{Poisson}( \lambda = N/M)$. But how do I condition on the sum being $N$?

Comment: You don't condition, you use the iid Poisson straightaway. That's why it's an approximation. See eg my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631487/asymptotics-of-the-classical-occupancy-problem/631534 That includes also an (optional) first order correction.

Comment: @leonbloy Okay, I see. In my application, $N >> k$. For instance $N \in [10^{2}, 10^{4}]$ and $k \in [2, 10]$. Perhaps there is a good approximation for this case specifically?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps this (or the references cited) helps ?https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsos.190198

Comment: @leonbloy I'll take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is that the $x_i$ are not independent binomials. The sum $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n$ is fixed to $N$, so if one of them is small, that makes the rest likely to be larger.

Consider the $\gamma=0$ case of your example, chosen because it's the easiest to compute. We have $\max\{x_2, x_3\} \le \gamma$ precisely when $X = (N,0,0)$, which happens with probability $(\frac13)^N$. But the individual probability that $x_i \le \gamma$ is $(\frac23)^N$, so your method gives $(\frac23)^{2N} = (\frac49)^N$ as the answer instead.

I don't expect a closed form to exist for your expression, because even $\Pr[x_i \le \gamma]$ has no closed form.

Comment: I figured they weren't independent. As $k \rightarrow M-1$, the approximation gets better. So I have to compute this probability numerically huh...